# Show/Hide text using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically I have 6 buttons and 6 paragraphs (each one button relating to a specific paragraph). I want to show a paragraph of text when a certain button is clicked, and then hide that paragraph when the button is clicked again.

I have looked through similar questions but cannot seem to get it to work. I think its because I have only started trying to use jquery and dont really understand the problem. All hep would be appreciated! thanks!

html:

```
     <div class="button"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
     <div class="button"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
     <div class="button"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>   


        <p><div id="text1">Paragraph 1</div></p>

        <p><div id="text2">Paragraph 2</div></p>

        <p><div id="text3">Paragraph 3</div></p>
```

javascript:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

     $("#text1").hide();
     $(".button").click(function(){
     $("#text1").toggle();

     $("#text2").hide();
     $(".button").click(function(){
     $("#text1").toggle();

     });
```

the first button should relate to the first paragraph and so on. Iv tried using the 'this' function to relate to a specific button but must be using it incorrectly because it dosent work.

Comment: You have hooked up the click event twice, to all 3 buttons! You need one click handler and add a data attribute to the buttons that you can use to select the correct text element.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you have to identify your different buttons, if you use the "button" class, you will always refer to the all 3 buttons.

Also you don't need to put a div element inside a p element.

So you can do something like this:

```
<div id="btn1" class="button"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
<div id="btn2" class="button"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
<div id="btn3" class="button"><a href="#">More..</a></div>   


<p id="p1">Paragraph 1</p>
<p id="p2">Paragraph 2</p>
<p id="p3">Paragraph 3</p>
```

Then, javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("p").hide();

    $("#btn1").click(function(){
         $("#p1").toggle();
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
         $("#p2").toggle();
    });

    $("#btn2").click(function(){
         $("#p2").toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this method and it worked perfect! Thanks for your help! One other thing, though, when I press the button to hide or show the page scrolls up o the very top - is there any way of stopping this from happening?

Comment: Yes, that's because the href="#", you can replace it with href="" and it will not scroll anywhere. Try it out!

Comment: no that dosent seem to work, after removing the # when I click the button the page jumps for a second and then dosent even show the text?

Comment: Well, you can remove the entire tag: `<div id="btn3" class="button">More..</div>`

Comment: Why did you repeat the same code over and over? What if there will be hundreds of buttons/paragraphs?

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="button"><div class="button float_l" t="1"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
 <div class="button"><div class="button float_l" t="2"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
 <div class="button"><div class="button float_l" t="3"><a href="#">More..</a></div>   


    <p><div id="text1">Paragraph 1</div></p>

    <p><div id="text2">Paragraph 2</div></p>

    <p><div id="text3">Paragraph 3</div></p>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $(".button").click(function(){
     $("#text" + $(this).attr('t')).toggle();
 }); 
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/pgZWA/

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for ?

**JS** :

```
$("#text1").hide();
$("#text2").hide();
$("#text3").hide();

$("#button1").click(function(){
    $("#text1").toggle();
});

$("#button2").click(function(){
    $("#text2").toggle();
});

$("#button3").click(function(){
    $("#text3").toggle();
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="button1"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div></div>
<div id="button2"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div></div>
<div id="button3"><div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div></div> 

<p><div id="text1">Paragraph 1</div></p>
<p><div id="text2">Paragraph 2</div></p>
<p><div id="text3">Paragraph 3</div></p>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6fdY9/1/)**

Comment: yes , I realised my main problem was not having the buttons named individually. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues to get sorted out in your markup, and after that you can achieve this by doing like that:

```
<!-- 
Notice your divs with class equal button have missing closing tags.
I've added them.
Also, I've added a data-rel attribute to each one of them to refer
to your related item to show/hide.
-->
<div class="button" data-rel="1">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<div class="button" data-rel="2">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<div class="button" data-rel="3">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<p>
    <div id="text1">Paragraph 1</div>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="text2">Paragraph 2</div>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="text3">Paragraph 3</div>
</p>
```

...

```
$(function () {
    // Hide all elements which id starts with text.
    $("[id^=text]").hide();

    $(".button").click(function () {
        // Look for the element with id equals text + 
        // the clicked element data-rel value.
        $("#text" + $(this).data("rel")).toggle();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4hum/)

[jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

You can also achieve the expected result by relying in the elements indexes:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<div class="button">
    <div class="button float_l"><a href="#">More..</a></div>
</div>
<p>
    <div id="text1">Paragraph 1</div>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="text2">Paragraph 2</div>
</p>
<p>
    <div id="text3">Paragraph 3</div>
</p>
```

...

```
$(function () {
    // Hide all elements which id starts with text.
    $("[id^=text]").hide();

    // Just for the elements with class equals
    // button but not with class float_l.
    $(".button:not(.float_l)").click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Look for the element which index matches
        // the clicked one.
        $("[id^=text]").eq($(this).index()).toggle();
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u4hum/2/)

[jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of different ways of approaching this. The most simple would be having a different ID on button, which corresponds to each paragraph.

**JS**

```
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    $('#text1').toggle();
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    $('#text2').toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="text1">Foo</p>
<p id="text2">Bar</p>
<input type="button" id="btn1" value="Toggle P1" />
<input type="button" id="btn2" value="Toggle P2" />
```

You could (instead of an ID for each button, use a data-* attribute. e.g.

**JS**

```
$('.button').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-pid');
    $('#text'+id).toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<p id="text1">Foo</p>
<p id="text2">Bar</p>
<input type="button" class="button" data-pid="1" value="Toggle P1" />
<input type="button" class="button" data-pid="2" value="Toggle P2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comment: You need one click handler and add a data attribute to the buttons that you can use to select the correct text element.

### Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/t93gf/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.para').hide();
    $(".button").click(function () {
        // Hide all paragraphs
        $('.para').hide();
        // Show the selected paragraph
        $('#' + $(this).data('id')).show();
    });
});
```