# Changing text displayed depending on the image of carousel in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

As the title states, I'm trying to change the text that is displayed depending on the image shown in the carousel. I want the text to show below the carousel, as captions won't fit. My code is as follows:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="character_page" class="fullscreen benguiat row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">


  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1>Characters</h1>
    <hr>

    <div id="character_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">


      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="6"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="7"></li>

      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active carousel_page">
          <!-- 2b page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/2b_carousel.png" alt="First slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- 9s page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/9s_carousel.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        </div>


        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- a2 page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/a2_carousel.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- commander page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/commander_carousel.jpg" alt="Fourth slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- operator page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/operator_carousel.jpg" alt="Fifth slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- pod page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pod_carousel.jpg" alt="Sixth slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- adam and eve page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/adam_eve_carousel.jpg" alt="Seventh slide">
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- pascal page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/pascal_carousel.jpg" alt="Eighth slide">
        </div>

      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#character_carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#character_carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried adding the text by creating another div inside carousel-item, but that ended up messing up the position of the carousel indicators and controls. I'm thinking the solution can be written in javascript, where I can hide all the text, then have the code look at the image that is displayed in the carousel and show the appropriate one. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, though, and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: Make a runnable snippet or jsfiddle like you will find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24701915/show-hide-text-using-jquery

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 5.0. I've tried running the code on jsfiddle but unfortunately I can't seem to make it work like it does on my browser.

Comment: If you save the fiddle and post a link, it is much easier for others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using Bootstrap 3.3.7 not Bootstrap 5.0. Check your code again. Make a very simple CSS -

```
.carousel-caption {
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;}
```

Unfortunately, it will give you white text on a white background. So you can't see anything. Fix this by adding one of the standard background color utility classes. For our example - **bg-dark** class.

Code Below -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style>
    .carousel-caption {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="character_page" class="fullscreen benguiat row">

  <div class="col-sm-3">


  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h1>Characters</h1>
    <hr>

    <div id="character_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">


      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="6"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#character_carousel" data-bs-slide-to="7"></li>

      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active carousel_page">
          <!-- 2b page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="First slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- 9s page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- a2 page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- commander page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Fourth slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- operator page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Fifth slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- pod page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Sixth slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- adam and eve page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Seventh slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item carousel_page">
          <!-- pascal page -->
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" alt="Eighth slide">
          <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block bg-dark mb-4">
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
            <h5>First slide label</h5>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#character_carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#character_carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>

      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```